# Should posting one of two forms in a page post all fields in both forms, or have I got a bug in my code

Tags: php, forms, post

I have two forms in a page. Have decided to update my post with more realistic code from the page itself...

```
 <form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <strong>Details of work carried out</strong>
 <textarea name="detailsOfWorkCarriedOut"></textarea>
 <strong>Materials used</strong>
 <textarea name="materialsUsed"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
 <input type="submit" value="Save">
 <form/>
 <br />
 <form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <strong>Details of work not carried out</strong>
 <textarea name="detailsOfWorkNotCarriedOut"></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
 <input type="submit" value="Save">
 </form>
```

"test.php" simply contains:

```
 <?php
print_r($_POST)
?>
```

No matter which form I post, I always get the same array returned:

```
Array ( [detailsOfWorkCarriedOut] => [materialsUsed] => [submitted] => true [detailsOfWorkNotCarriedOut] => )
```

Why is this?

Comment: Did you validate your document with something like http://validator.w3.org/ ? Maybe your "real" document doesn't look like the example snippet because of errors in the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the

```
<form/>
```

at line 8: replace it with

```
</form>
```

:)

Comment: If you do what I'm saying, you'll get what you expect

Comment: Sorry! :) I don't know why I thought you did the negative vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, browsers submit only the fields in the form in which the submit button is nested. You could use JavaScript to monitor form submissions and include values from the other form in the submission, but you're seeing the expected behavior right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is inside **one** form, so, it only submits that **one** form.

So, no, `$_POST` should not contain data that comes from both forms : it should only contain data coming from the submitted one.

*(but, why don't you try it ? )*

Something ugly like this should do the trick, if you're only willing to test :

```
<form method="get">
    <input name="a" type="text">
</form>

<form method="get">
    <input name="b" type="text">
</form>

<?php

var_dump($_GET);
```

*(Yeah, it's ugly, I said ^^ )*

If you type something into the first field and submit by pressing ENTER, you'll get :

```
array
  'a' => string 'aa' (length=2)
```

And, with the second field :

```
array
  'b' => string 'second field' (length=12)
```

So, only one form each time :-)